# scaleY property not maintained properly for small screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

- I am tryng to fix a css bug for mobile screens
- when I click section 1 content opens and if i move till the bottom of the section one content and after that if I click section 1 content closes.
- but I dont see section 2 after that I see section 3 since the screen moves upwards.
- how to retain the section 2 in our screen.
- am I doing anything wrong with the scaleY property.
- providing the related code below

**I used   scrollIntoView but still not point to second one any idea???**

**I used   window.scrollTo(0, 0) but still not point to second one any idea???**

```or-tag-here
 .television .chromecast .sun .sunItem > .bulb {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform .5s, max-height .5s;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-height: 0;
    transform-origin: center top;
}

 .television .chromecast .sun .sunItem.selected > .bulb {
    transform: scaleY(1);
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to invoke properly on the select function

```
onSelect() {
this.props.onSelect(this.props.id);
this.focusDiv();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behaviour. The scroll position is retained but you remove content from the top of the screen so you end up further down in the page.

It's always a bad idea to collapse the previous elements when expanding a new one, especially on mobile.

To fix that, you will need to script a scrolling to the top of the open section. That could easily be achieved using `jQuery.ScrollTo()` or something similar, but to be honest, I would just leave the previous sections open, unless the users have a tendency to scroll back up and that would require to much scrolling to get back to the top of the page. Other UX solutions like a scroll to top link might come in handy to solve that.

Comment: thanks for your reply...it's so confusing...can you update in my code

Comment: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime"

Comment: can you tell me how to use in react...I will do it

Comment: Use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-component. It took me 2sec to Google it, seriously.

Comment: I saw that but I need to implement without this extra plugin...any other example

Comment: Why do you use a framework like react if you can't use plugins? You'd rather just use plain JS then. See of it's done in the plugin and replicate it then, but it's seems convoluted.

Comment: I used   window.scrollTo(0, 0) but still not point to second one any idea???  http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/102/

Comment: Well, what did you expect? You need to calculate the position of the element you want to scroll the window to, not 0,0, which is obviously the top of the page. Btw I'm done here, please put at least a tiny bit of effort trying to solving this

Comment: any easy way to calculate the position...not sure how to point to second when we click first section content

Comment: hey I tried everything but still its not working, I used scrollview that also not working...can you tell me how to proceed http://jsfiddle.net/b4L6kyg4/103/